# Qt. Как плотнее сдвинуть кнопки в компановке QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите, пожалуйста с компоновщиком. Сделал такой «калькуляторный» интерфейс на Qt 4.8.2 с помощью QGridLayout.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сдвинуть кнопки плотнее друг к другу и оставить свободное место, и снизу окна приложения. Есть ли QGridLayout команды, позволяющие сделать это?

Если есть такая возможность, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вложенную сетку меньше внешней. К примеру задать размер сетки ptopLayout 6X6, а внутренней QtL 5X5. Ведь нельзя задать размер  сетки напрямую при ее создании.

Справа оставил место путем вложения еще одного компановщика Qgrid в «верхний».

Код моего интерфейса.

файл main.cpp

```
#include "qgrid.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGrid w;

    w.resize(300, 250);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Файл QGrid.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include "qgrid.h"

QGrid::QGrid(QWidget* pwgt/*= 0*/) : QWidget(pwgt) 
{
    m_plcd = new QLCDNumber(15);
    m_plcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
    m_plcd->setMinimumSize(150, 50);

    //Layout setup

    QGridLayout* ptopLayout = new QGridLayout;
    QGridLayout* QtL = new QGridLayout;
    ptopLayout ->addLayout(QtL,1,0,1,1);
    ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 4);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("1", 40, 80),1,0,2,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("2", 100, 30),1,1,1,2);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("3", 40, 80),1,3,2,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("4", 100, 30),2,1,1,2);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("5", 40, 40),3,0,1,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("6", 40, 40),3,1,1,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("7", 40, 40),3,2,1,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("8", 40, 40),3,3,1,1);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("9", 110, 30),4,0,2,2);
    QtL->addWidget(createButton("0",110,30),4,2,2,2);
    setLayout(ptopLayout);
}

QPushButton* QGrid::createButton(const QString& str, const int& width, const int& hight)
{
    QPushButton* pcmd = new QPushButton(str);
    pcmd->setFixedSize(width, hight);
    connect(pcmd, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotButtonClicked()));

    return pcmd;
}

void QGrid::slotButtonClicked()
{
    QString str = ((QPushButton*)sender())->text();

    if (str.contains(QRegExp("[0-9]"))) {
        m_strDisplay += str;
        m_plcd->display(m_strDisplay.toDouble());
    }
    else 
    {
        m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
        m_strDisplay = "";
        m_plcd->display("0");
    }
}
```

Файл Qgrid.h

```
#ifndef QGRID_H
#define QGRID_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStack>

class QLCDNumber;
class QPushButton;

class QGrid : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLCDNumber* m_plcd;
    QStack<QString> m_stk;
    QString m_strDisplay;

public:
    QGrid(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QPushButton* createButton(const QString& str, const int& width, const int& height);
    void display();


public slots:
    void slotButtonClicked();
};

#endif // QGRID_H
```

Comment: Вы напутали с гридами и индексами строк/столбцов в них. Исправленную и проверенную версию добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть методы задания пространства между виджетами в клетке и границей клетки:

```
QGridLayout::setHorizontalSpacing(int value);
QGridLayout::setVerticalSpacing(int value);
QGridLayout::setSpacing(int value);
```

А также у всех лэйаутов (QLayout) есть метод установки отступа всего контента от краев (маржин):

```
QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
QLayout::setMargin(int value); // устаревшая функция
```

Кроме того, я рекомендую немного изменить ваш код, чтобы он стал более понятным для вас в первую очередь. Привожу пример только измененной части

Конструктор:

```
//...
QGridLayout* QtL = new QGridLayout;
QtL->setMargin(0); // отступ содержимого
QtL->setSpacing(0); // пространство внутри клеток

QtL->addWidget(createButton("1", 40, 80),  0,0,2,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("2", 100, 30), 0,1,1,2);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("3", 40, 80),  0,3,2,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("4", 100, 30), 1,1,1,2);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("5", 40, 40),  2,0,1,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("6", 40, 40),  2,1,1,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("7", 40, 40),  2,2,1,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("8", 40, 40),  2,3,1,1);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("9", 110, 30), 3,0,1,2);
QtL->addWidget(createButton("0",110,30),   3,2,1,2);

QWidget* w = new QWidget; // Нужно для того, чтобы прижать LCD к верхней части окна
w->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
w->setLayout(QtL);

QGridLayout* ptopLayout = new QGridLayout;
ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 1);
ptopLayout->addWidget(w, 1, 0, 1, 1);
ptopLayout->setRowStretch(1, 2);

setLayout(ptopLayout);
```

А чтобы получить вот такую картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вам надо в методе createButton взамен установки размера каждой кнопки, сделать так:

```
pcmd->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```